# Calculate end date from start date and days per week data

Tags: algorithm, date, calendar, formula, date-arithmetic

I have the following variables

```
INPUT
start_date = 1 JUN 2020
session_days = [Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday]
sessions_per_week_count = 7 # from above data
total sesions = 20


OUTPUT
20 JUN 2020
```

from the above data, we can calculate that end_date should be 20 Jun 2018

I need help writing algorithm/formula to calculate the end date with variable input data based on the calender.

any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you reach that end_date? Then, convert that reasoning to a step-by-step algorithm, and show us. We can help diagnosing an error on the algorithm, but we will not do the algorithm for you.

Comment: @samthegolden I initially calculated that by marking on the calendar, I guess I need to work with the calendar and developed an algorithm around it. (currently writing in ruby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I came up with a pretty simple method in ruby

```
def session_dates(date, weekdays_arr, number_of_working_days)
  result = []
  while result.size < number_of_working_days
    if weekdays_arr.include? date.wday
      result << date
    end
    date += 1
  end
  result
end
```

by calling a method like this

```
start_date = Date.today.beginning_of_month
session_days_in_week = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6] # week starts from 0(Sunday) 
result = session_dates(start_date, session_days_in_week, 20)
```

I can get all dates on the weekdays in output

```
[
    [ 0] Mon, 01 Jun 2020,
    [ 1] Tue, 02 Jun 2020,
    [ 2] Wed, 03 Jun 2020,
    [ 3] Thu, 04 Jun 2020,
    [ 4] Fri, 05 Jun 2020,
    [ 5] Sat, 06 Jun 2020,
    [ 6] Sun, 07 Jun 2020,
    [ 7] Mon, 08 Jun 2020,
    [ 8] Tue, 09 Jun 2020,
    [ 9] Wed, 10 Jun 2020,
    [10] Thu, 11 Jun 2020,
    [11] Fri, 12 Jun 2020,
    [12] Sat, 13 Jun 2020,
    [13] Sun, 14 Jun 2020,
    [14] Mon, 15 Jun 2020,
    [15] Tue, 16 Jun 2020,
    [16] Wed, 17 Jun 2020,
    [17] Thu, 18 Jun 2020,
    [18] Fri, 19 Jun 2020,
    [19] Sat, 20 Jun 2020
]
```

and obviously the last element in result array is ending_date.